Ideal Op amp - output voltage equation
As per definition, op amp senses the difference between 2 input voltages and multiply with K factor then have output voltage, this below probably finds Vo. My equation is Vo = K(Vp-Vn), Vp is voltage at non inverting terminal = 1, Vn is voltage at inverting terminal = 2, then Vo=K(1-2)=-K, is this correct?



No, your answer is not correct.

can you help me shortly with equation?

We don't solve homework problems for you here, but we can provide hints.  For an ideal op-amp (presumably infinite gain, so K is infinite) with negative feedback, what's the voltage difference between the + and - terminals?  What's the current through (and therefore voltage across) the 10 K resistor?  What's the impact of the 2 K resistor on the output voltage (again, an ideal amp)? Then what's KVL from ground to the output of the amplifier?

I am following this definition circuit [url=https://anh.moe/view/b7sogB][img]https://cdn.anh.moe/f/Y5n06m.png-webp[/img][/url], V2 = 1, V1=2, then the difference is -1, then Vo  = k*-1

Can you see the first picture and my solution already given

Yes, your first picture is a different circuit.  The second circuit that you initially asked about has negative feedback.  So maybe review op-amps with feedback.  Maybe start with an op-amp non-inverting voltage follower to see how that works.

the 1st pic is not apply for all op amp working generally?

Well, ask yourself if an ideal op-amp has infinite gain, or even very large K, how useful would it be generally in the case of the first diagram?  Why are op-amps generally used with negative feedback?  If you can answer those questions you may then be able to solve the lower circuit.

In cct b), Vin- must be equal to Vin+ (the controlling input) if the output is linear and 10k has almost no input current so no voltage drop so what is Vo? (Simple )

Is the 4-wires cross to the right of the output of the op-amp a node or not? If it is (and I suppose it is), you must mark it with a dot. https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/reference/chpt-9/wires-and-connections/

I'll take you through the steps necessary to understand this problem, and resolve it, but only so far. Start with this:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
With the caveats that this op-amp has finite gain \$A\$, in contrast to an ideal op-amp with infinite gain, and that a real op-amp cannot ever have output \$V_O\$ greater its own positive supply, or less than its own negative supply, the following is always true:
$$ V_O = A(V_P-V_Q) $$
Let's examine the effect of the 2kΩ resistor connected to the output:

simulate this circuit
Your own first diagram shows the op-amp's output being derived from a dependent source. This implies that \$V_O\$ is a voltage source whose output does not care what is connected to it. Therefore resistor R1 has no influence on \$V_O\$. It does not influence the potentials at P or Q either, and consequently the relationship above is still true, regardless of R1:
$$ V_O = A(V_P-V_Q) $$
R1 can be disregarded.
Now let's look at R2, the 10kΩ resistor, without the 2V source in place:

simulate this circuit
A characteristic of the op-amp is that it has infinite input resistance, and therefore input current is zero. There's nowhere else for current to enter or leave the path containing R2, so current through R2 is:
$$ I=0 $$
By Ohm's law, this means that the voltage \$V_{R2}\$ across R2 (as shown on voltmeter VM1) is:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_{R2} &= I \times R_2 \\ \\
&= 0 \times 10k\Omega \\ \\
&= 0 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
If there's no potential difference across R2 then:
$$ V_Q = V_O $$
Just because it's interesting, let's find \$V_O\$ for this scenario:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_O &= A(V_P-V_Q) \\ \\
&= A(V_P-V_O) \\ \\
&= A\cdot V_P -A\cdot V_O \\ \\
V_O + A\cdot V_O &= A\cdot V_P \\ \\
V_O(1 + A) &= A\cdot V_P \\ \\
V_O &= \frac{A}{1+A}V_P
\end{aligned}
$$
Remember, \$A\$ is very large, so \$\frac{A}{1+A}\approx 1\$, and therefore:
$$ V_O \approx V_P $$
Now let's add the 2V source:

simulate this circuit
There's still no way for current to enter or leave the path of R2, and op-amp input current is still zero, so \$I=0\$ still and \$V_{R2}=0\$ also. However, due to V2, the equality \$V_Q=V_O\$ is no longer true. By KVL:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_Q &= V_O - V_{R2} + V_2 \\ \\
&= V_O - 0 + 2 \\ \\
V_Q &= V_O + 2 \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Now calculate \$V_O\$ again, using this slightly different expression for \$V_Q\$:
$$
\begin{aligned}
V_O &= A(V_P-V_Q) \\ \\
&= A(V_P-\left[V_O+2\right]) \\ \\
\end{aligned}
$$
That's as far as I'll go. Use the fact that \$A\$ is huge to find an expression for \$V_O\$, in the same way I did above. Then, since the other voltage source sets potential \$V_P\$, so \$V_P\$ is known, you can fully evaluate \$V_O\$.
